# C++ // Invalid use of nonstatic data member

Tags: c++

Code::blocks says "Invalid use of nonstatic data member" . Why this error ?

```
class counter {

public:
counter()=default;      //default contructor

friend void upg(){++val;}  //function that increases "val" by 1

private:
    int val=0;

};
```

Comment: There is no implicit `this` pointer because `upg()` is not a member function.

Answer (score 4):

`upg()` is not a member function. Therefore it cannot access `val` without an instance of `counter`. This would compile, although it probably doesn't make much sense:

```
friend void upg() { counter c; c.val++; }
```

A better solution might be to make `upg()` a member,

```
class counter
{
public:
  counter()=default;    // some pointless code "documentation"

  void upg(){ ++val; }  //function that increases "val" by 1

private:
    int val=0;
};
```

or, if you really need a non-member, give it a `counter` parameter:

```
friend void upg(counter& c) { c.val++; }
```

Comment: Why is not a member function ?

ps: why cant i use

friend void upg(counter &c){++val;}

instead of

friend void upg(counter &c){++c.val;}

The implicit "this" pointer, it would not do just that?

Comment: @themagiciant95 That is what that friend declaration means. That the function declared as friend is not a member of the class it is declared as a friend in.

Comment: "Why is not a member function ?" Because you declared it to be a friend, not a member. You probably just want to remove `friend` to make it a member.

Answer (score 1):

#### I think you don't understand what a friend function is.

Let's create an object with a friend function, a regular function, and a method:

```
#include <set>
#include <utility>

class counter {
    public:
        void method_inc();    
        friend void friend_inc(counter & c);

    private:
        int val = 0;
};

void counter::method_inc() {
    this->val++;    

void friend_inc(counter & c) {
    c.val++;
}

void nonfriend_inc(counter & c) {
    c.val++; // Error: val is private.
}

int main() {
    counter c;

    c.method_inc();
    friend_inc(c);
    nonfriend_inc(c);
}
```

Let's talk about our functions:

1. The method has an implicit `this` that allows it to access the object it was called with. In this case, that would be the `c` in `c.member_inc()`.
2. The function `nonfriend_inc()` has to have an argument of the object that it is using. But it will also fail to build because `counter::val` is private and it's not a friend function.
3. The function `friend_inc()` also doesn't have an implicit `this`. But because it is a friend function to `class counter`, it can access the private members of that object.